# Advanced Custom Field Repeater is Returning Everything Correctly Except The Image

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Experiencing a rather odd behavior in my Wordpress site that is running ACF Pro. The loop returns 3 variables, a title, an icon, and a description. The title and the description output perfectly, however, it returns the same image each iteration over the loop. Anybody have any suggestions?

```
<?php
if ( have_rows( 'additional_services' ) ): ?>
<div class="outer-three-col">
  <?php
  while ( have_rows( 'additional_services' ) ): the_row();
    $service_title = get_sub_field( 'service_title' );
    $service_icon = get_sub_field( 'service_icon' );
    $service_description = get_sub_field( 'service_description' );
  ?>
  <div class="inner-three-col">
    <div class="row-fluid-wrapper">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <?php
        if ( !empty( $service_icon ) ) { ?>
        <div class="imag-module"> 
           <img src="<?php echo $service_icon['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $service_title; ?>"> 
        </div>
        <?php   }  ?>
        <div class="text-module">
          <h4><?php echo $service_title; ?></h4>
          <p><span style="font-weight: 400;"><?php echo $service_description; ?></span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: When the image field has miss behaved for me in the past I've had to go back in to the admin of ACF and double check the image field is set to array, even if it is, sometimes I've had to click update for it to work, maybe try that?

Comment: There appears to be a conflict between Advanced Custom Fields and the Network Media Library plugin which allows the sharing of the library across multiple site when using Multisite mode